# Coherence between lifts in a model category

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

I'm afraid that my question won't be specific but I can edit it depending on the reactions I will get. In a functor category $[\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}]$ (typically a presheaves category) with a model structure you have sometimes to exhibit a lift in a commutative square (to show a map is a fibration for instance), to do that one can sometimes use the fact that pointwise you get a commutative square with a trivial cofibration on the left side and a fibration on the right side, so pointwise you have a lift. Unfortunetly, all together those lifts don't form a natural transformation (and so a lift in the original square) since the naturality condition doesn't hold. Are there some tools and technics to handle this kind of problem ?

Best

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but this seems like the sort of issue $\infty$-categories handle better than model categories. Certainly functor categories between $\infty$-categories are much better behaved. See e.g. Lurie's books.

Comment: Coherence of lifts is handled by considering _algebraic_ model structures – cf the work of Garner and Riehl.

Comment: thanks for the reference on algebraic model structure, this is probably the way I need to explore.

Comment: @Justin: I agree but I'm currently using (2,1)-categories, not genuine infinity ones. Actually, I tried these last days to work with 2-weak factorisation systems but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Any model category gives rise to an $\infty$-category by inverting weak equivalences. Are you saying that in your case this $\infty$-category is the nerve of a $2$-category? This seems unlikely except in degenerate cases.

Comment: I haven't a knowledge of higher category. Do you mean that a localization (let say left Bousfield localization) gives rise to a genuine $\infty$-category still equiped with a model structure or better a model $\infty$-category ?

Comment: I don't think you can prove a morphism is a fibration by looking at the associated infinity-category.  I think Zhen Lin's comment is more useful.

Comment: In passing to the associated quasicategory, one forgets about fibrations and cofibrations: after all, every morphism is weakly equivalent to a fibration and a cofibration, and in a general quasicategory, equivalent morphisms cannot be distinguished.